# NullpointerException when generateCertificates() with CertificateFactory

Tags: java, android, performance, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

In my Android project, I have put my certificate file under project's `raw/` folder as `raw/mycert.p12` .

Then, I try to get a `X509Certificate` instance by doing the following:

```
//Get input stream of mycert.p12, the input stream is not null
InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(com.my.app.R.raw.mycert);

//Get an instance of CertificateFactory
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

//Get buffered input stream
InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

//Generate certificate instance
//NullpointerException here...
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificates(bis);
```

I have also tried to manually install this certificate (mycert.p12) , I am sure it is a x.509 type certificate.

But why I get **NullpointerException** when generate the instance of it from input stream?

Comment: well both can be null. Why dont you check on the logs and see which on e in null? Also you can use the debugger to find which reference is null

Comment: You are right, both can be null, why I am so sure that the NullpointerException is for the generated certificate is because I have debug logs, which shows me it is null & inputStream is not null.

Comment: Why don't you give the full stacktrace? If the exception occurs on the last row (rather than somewhere inside the call), then the only possible reason is `cf == null`. Btw., why the "performance" tag?

Answer (score 0):

Some one had faced similar issue  Refering the answer: Context.anymethod I refer to the R file of the app, so I can't give the resource ID got from the R file of my library project.

It will compile, because the library project jar file contains the resource (R.raw.xml_file), but the call to context.something will always give null as a result because it refers to the app R file, that does not have that particular resource in it.

I finally had to put my xml file in the res/raw folder of the app, and access the xml_file raw resource in this way:

```
int xml_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("xml_file_name", "raw", context.getPackageName());

// Getting input stream from xml file
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(xml_id);
```

Comment: can you post full exception stack trace